# Unable to open the landing page on server

Tags: asp.net, url

I am using asp.net 3.5.

My Hosting provider has given me a folder to upload my publish application, now when I am entering www.example.com, I am not getting my homepage, but when I am running the same application on my local I am getting home page.

Please let me know what I have to modify so that when usertype www.example.com it will open like www.example.com/homepage.aspx

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard default page name for ASP.Net is `Default.aspx`, not `homepage.aspx`.

Rename the landing page to `Default.aspx`

Or, create a `Default.aspx` page and have it do a redirect `homepage.aspx`

Or, see if your hosting provider will configure your site to serve up `homepage.aspx` as the default page.

Comment: I have done the same, my site already have a default.aspx page, also I have modified my app to first go to default.aspx and then redirect to homepage.aspx.
It's working in local but not in server.

Please help.

Comment: Older versions of IIS aren't set up to check default.aspx initially.  You have to either change the site in IIS to look for default.aspx or provide a default.asp page (no 'x')  that just has a quick `<% Server.Transfer("default.aspx") %>`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a domain name issue?

Locally you probably use http://localhost/homepage.aspx?

Has the domain name "www.mysite.com" been configured/activated for you by your provider?